# unable to get all loggers using log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext logContext = 
                 (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext)
                       LogManager.getContext(false);
Map<String, LoggerConfig> map = logContext.getConfiguration().getLoggers();
```

I am getting only root logger but I need to get all loggers and I want change logger level at run time.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
LoggerContext logContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Collection<Logger> allLoggers = logContext.getLoggers();
```

Comment: I am not getting list of class with above solution. Can you please guide?